# Azure Monitor - REST API Custom Log - .Net

Tags: .net, azure, azure-monitoring

We are using Azure Monitor custom logs to collect logs from several applications. For pushing data we are using Data Collector API which is well [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-collector-api).

Is there a REST API that allows to search custom logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the API in the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/query/get .

Below will be the sample call

GET https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/63613592-b6f7-4c3d-a390-22ba13102111/query?query=Usage | take 10&timespan=PT12H

Comment: You need to authorize yourself to Azure and have a context. If you already have a Azure context you can reuse the same context and query the Log analytics.

Answer (score 1):

Surely you can use the [`application insights`](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/) api to search your custom logs.

```
GET /v1/apps/{appId}/metrics/{metricId}
```